# How to use Gedit to compile C program on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, gcc, valgrind, gedit, runc

Im a c program student.
right now I am using VirtualBox to run Linux(ubuntu with school preset. it already had gedit, runC, gcc, valgrind)

Now i wanna do c programming on my Mac os,
My question is how do i install gcc ,valgrind,runC in order to use the MAC gedit ro run C programs?
right now I only have gedit on my MAC OS.

And is runC a default gedit plugin or I have to download by myself?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

XCode, the developer environment for MacOS comes free, but not installed by default.  It is much better.  You can get it by going to the Apple Developer site.  The most current version requires paying for access to the bleeding edge (pre-release).  You want the public (2nd most recent) version.